# Not able to refresh ViewPager on Data change

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am using ViewPagerIndicator by jake 
https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

I am populating string[] CONTENT on TestFragmentAdapter with all the file's name stored in my SDcard..

My problem is that with in my app using another activity , when I delete some of the files and then go back to ViewPager activity(via some button), it doesn't refresh its CONTENT data and instead display blank data because the file is not on SDcard anymore (Data which I am displaying on viewpager is actually reading all data from txt files on sdcard).

Please help me!!!..this is a great ViewPager indicator and I really want to use it

this is how I am populating it

```
private static File path = new       File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"Shikhatxt");
private static File[] files = path.listFiles();
private static String[] CONTENT = new String[files.length];

private int mCount = CONTENT.length;
```

I am not able to figure out how to refresh this data every time I click on ViewPager Button...

Thanks